# slf4j conflicting with GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt, hive

I'm working on a GWT project in eclipse that makes calls to Apache Hive from the webpage. The architecture is something like this.

In the GWT project. the use puts a hive query on the webpage. The webpage sends this query to the server class using GWT RPC. The server makes a call to another java class in another eclipse project. This project has the hive jdbc driver, which calls hive that is running on a VM (CDH3).

I wrote a unit test that calls the GWT server class and sends a Hive query and it executes fine, but when I run he project and try to send the query from the webpage. It throws a  runtime error. It seems to have some conflict with the slf4j classes included in the second eclipse project that has the Hive JDBC driver. I am guessing, there is some conflict between GWT server classes that are called at runtime and the slf4j classes included in the other project. By the way, the second project is included in the build path of the first one, but not the other way.

Here's the error:

```
[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.unitest.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server-side dependencies have to live within the `WEB-INF/lib` of the GWT project (just like any other WAR).

Comment: Hmmmm! Didn't know that. I'm new to web development. Is there a way to get other eclipse projects into Web-Inf/lib without modifying project structures.

Comment: If you're not using Maven or similar build system with dependency management built-in, then you'll have to package your _other project_ as a JAR (AFAIK there should be an option in Eclipse somewhere in the menus) and copy that JAR into the `WEB-INF/lib` (rinse and repeat each time you modify the _other project_)

Comment: Huh! Turns out this is not why its not working. I created another stub function in the Hive JDBC project and called it from the webpage and that worked just fine. The problem has something to do with hive. The exception seems to be getting triggered when I instantiate a connection with Hive. Here's the code
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + "/default", "", ""); //This is the statement that is raising the exception.